# internal/validators.js:124 throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "e of type string. Received undefined"

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, multer

I have been having this issue with `react` trying to upload file using `formData`. I keep getting
this error. Thank you for your help.
my setUp:
`react-scripts: "^4.0.3"`, `node 14`, `multer: "^1.4.3",`

> internal/validators.js:124 throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:  The "e of type string. Received
> undefined"

I have deleted my `node_modules` and run `npm install` but the same, I tried updating my `react-scripts` to the latest version still the same

Here is my react code section

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (newFile) {
    console.log(newFile); // the file data is available
    try {
      const name = Date.now() + newFile.name;
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', newFile);
      data.append('name', name);
      await axios.post('/tickets/upload', data); // I have set {headers : {"Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data"}} still not working
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
};
```

Here is the code that handles the upload. note: it is working fine with `postman` (I can upload successfully with `postman`).

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    try {
      const newTicket = new Ticket(req.body)
      const ticket = await newTicket.save()
      res.status(201).json(ticket)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err)
    }
  } else {
    res.status(403).json('You are allowed to create a ticket')
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this somehow? Thanks

Comment: Actually it's been while. I found another way to the solution! I might send you I message if I remember !

Comment: hi, it would definitely be helpful. Can you describe the solution in an answer here?